# crop some text from segment text

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a div:

`<div id="crop"><span> text - 123 views</span></div>`

I want crop from "-" to "v" ,thanks

Comment: can you explain what you are wanting to do a little better. The term crop is to remove something like crop an image but i do not quite get crop from - to v. Also is the div user created or wordpress plugin core created.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wqr3/

```
var $span = $('#crop').find('> span');

$span.text(
    $span.text().replace(/^[\s\S]*-\s+(\d+)\s+[\s\S]*$/m, '$1')
);
```